CGAL 3D mesh clean subdomain boundaries
I am using mesh_3D_gray_vtk_image.cpp to generate a 3D mesh from a segmented image with several subdomains. The code works without any compilation issues however, the generated meshes seem to have problems separating the different subdomains like it is shown in the image bad domain separation.
I am using feature protection both inside the image and in bbox and also tried using weights (as in mesh_3D_weighted_image_with_detection_of_features). I also tried tuning the facet parameters (reducing facet size and distance) as well as edge length and cell size but nothing does the trick.
Is there any way I can guarantee that there is no cell sharing between certain subdomains or is a problem with the image resolution?
Thanks for your help
here is a copy of my code:
I tried:
Feature protection in bbox and inside the image
weights for different subdomains
fine tuning of facet, edge and cell parameters

I was expecting a clear separation between certain subdomains where the voxel value is equal to 0
#include <vtkNew.h>
#include <vtkImageData.h>
#include <vtkNIFTIImageReader.h>
#include <vtkImageReader.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_criteria_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Labeled_mesh_domain_3.h>
#include <CGAL/make_mesh_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Image_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/read_vtk_image_data.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/output_to_vtu.h>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/functional.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include "mesh_3D_gray_vtk_image.h"
#include <CGAL/Mesh_domain_with_polyline_features_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_3/Detect_features_on_image_bbox.h>
#include <CGAL/Mesh_3/Detect_features_in_image.h>


//typedef short Image_word_type;

// Domain
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Labeled_mesh_domain_3<K> Image_domain;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_domain_with_polyline_features_3<Image_domain> Mesh_domain;

#ifdef CGAL_CONCURRENT_MESH_3
typedef CGAL::Parallel_tag Concurrency_tag;
#else
typedef CGAL::Sequential_tag Concurrency_tag;
#endif

// Triangulation
typedef CGAL::Mesh_triangulation_3<Mesh_domain, CGAL::Default, Concurrency_tag>::type Tr;
typedef CGAL::Mesh_complex_3_in_triangulation_3<Tr> C3t3;

// Criteria
typedef CGAL::Mesh_criteria_3<Tr> Mesh_criteria;
namespace params = CGAL::parameters;



namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Loads image
    if (argc < 5) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <nii in file> <vtu out file> <cell_size> <element_ratio>"
            << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    vtkImageData* vtk_image = nullptr;

    fs::path path(argv[1]);

    vtkNIFTIImageReader* reader = vtkNIFTIImageReader::New();
    reader->SetFileName(argv[1]);
    reader->Update();
    vtk_image = reader->GetOutput();
    vtk_image->Print(std::cerr);
    std::cout << ".nii image loaded";

    if (vtk_image == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "No image loaded" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    CGAL::Image_3 image = CGAL::IO::read_vtk_image_data(vtk_image);
    if (image.image() == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "could not create a CGAL::Image_3 from the vtk image\n";
        return 0;
    }


    /// [Domain creation]
    Mesh_domain domain = Mesh_domain::create_labeled_image_mesh_domain(image,
        params::features_detector = CGAL::Mesh_3::Detect_features_on_image_bbox(),
        params::features_detector = CGAL::Mesh_3::Detect_features_in_image());
    /// [Domain creation]



      // Sizing field: set global size to 8 and kidney size (label 127) to 3
  
    double cell_size = boost::lexical_cast<double>(argv[3]);
    double facet_angle =25;
    double facet_distance = 0.05 * cell_size;
    double element_ratio = boost::lexical_cast<double>(argv[4]);;
    double min_size = element_ratio * cell_size;
    int volume_dimension = 3;


    // Mesh criteria
    Mesh_criteria criteria(params::facet_angle(facet_angle).
        facet_size(cell_size).
        facet_min_size(min_size).
        facet_distance(facet_distance).
        facet_topology(CGAL::FACET_VERTICES_ON_SAME_SURFACE_PATCH).
        edge_size(cell_size).
        edge_min_size(min_size).
        cell_radius_edge_ratio(2).
        cell_size(cell_size).
        cell_min_size(min_size));


    // Meshing
    C3t3 c3t3 = CGAL::make_mesh_3<C3t3>(domain, criteria,
        params::lloyd(params::time_limit(30)).
            odt(params::time_limit(30).
            perturb(params::time_limit(15).sliver_bound(30)).
            exude(params::time_limit(10).sliver_bound(30))));
    // Output
    std::ofstream file(argv[2]);
    CGAL::IO::output_to_vtu(file, c3t3, CGAL::IO::ASCII);

    return 0;


